# How to add indicator constraints in Pulp Python?

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I have a problem that I don't know how to add indicator constraints in `pulp`. Can anyone help me?
For example: I have a decision variable `x[(i,j)]`, LpBinary and a continuous variable `u[i]` When `x[(i,j)]` equals `1`, then `u[i] + q[j] == u[j]` (`q` is just the demand of customers) Thank you for your helping.

Comment: what happens with `x[(i,j)] == 0`  ?

Comment: nothing happens @StuartMitchell, I just now concern about when x[(i,j)] = 1
For example: x[1,2] = 1 => u[1]+q[2]=u[2] . It seems like I update the data for continuous variables u[i

Comment: Can you give a minimal complete and verifiable example? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO!

My interpretation of your question is that you have binary variables `x[(i,j)]`, and continuos variables `u[i]`. When `x[(i,j)]==1` then you want to enforce a constraint as follows `u[i] + q[j] == u[j]`. If `x[(i,j)]==0` then no such constraint is enforced.

This can be done as follows:

```
for i in set_I:
    for j in set_J:
        u[j] >= u[i] + q[j] - (1 - x[(i,j)])*M
        u[j] <= u[i] + q[j] + (1 - x[(i,j)])*M
```

Where `M` is a value that is a bit bigger than the largest possible range in `u[i]` values + the largest possible `q[j]` value. To understand why this works consider the two cases, first if `x[(i,j)]==1` these constraints become:

```
    u[j] >= u[i] + q[j]
    u[j] <= u[i] + q[j]
```

Which can be abbreviated as: `u[j] == u[i] + q[j]`, the constraint you want in the `x[(i,j)]==1` case.

In the `x[(i,j)]==0` case, these constraints become:

```
    u[j] >= u[i] + q[j] - M
    u[j] <= u[i] + q[j] + M
```

Recall that M is a large number, what we are saying is `u[j] >= some_value - large_number`, which provided you choose `M` so that its large enough will not have any effect at all (as required). Similarly the constraint `u[j] <= some_value + large_number` has not effect provided `M` is sufficiently large.